# Reading data from web service using angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to read data from a WS and attach it to a scope variable in angularjs.

The controller API looks like this:

```
 public class ContactsController : ApiController
{
    // GET: api/Contacts
    public List<Contact> Get()
    {
        List<Contact> cl = new List<Contact>();
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConStr"].ConnectionString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT * FROM Contacts", con);

        try
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                Contact c = new Contact();
                c.Name = rdr["Name"].ToString();
                c.Phone = (int)rdr["Phone"];
                c.Mail = rdr["Mail"].ToString();
                c.City = rdr["City"].ToString();
                c.Address = rdr["Address"].ToString();
                c.Image = rdr["Image"].ToString();
                cl.Add(c);
            }
            rdr.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }
        return cl;
    }
```

The HTML controller looks like this:

```
controller: function ($scope, $http) {
                            var url = "http://example.com"
                            $http.get(url + "/api/Contacts").then(function (res) {
                                $scope.contacts = res.data;
                            }, function (err) { alert(err);});
```

but res.data seems to contain nothing. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Can you cross-check API response through POSTMAN(Chrome Plugin) and see if response does have data? If its not then its problem with API.

Comment: @Jadenkun It doesn't answer the question but I am pretty sure the error is not at the html controller. Just to double check see if res directly has all the data instead of res.data. If that is also empty then someone should come back with what needs to be changed in API controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have just returning `List<Contact>` object, You can directly use the `response` instead of `response.data`.

Just try this code instead of yours

```
$scope.contacts = res;
```

**Should check `return cl;` is returning any result**